# Parsing key value in an csv file using shell script

Tags: shell, unix, grep

Given csv input file

```
Id Name Address Phone
---------------------

100 Abc NewYork     1234567890  
101 Def San Antonio 9876543210  
102 ghi Chicago     7412589630  
103 GHJ Los Angeles 7896541259
```

How do we grep/command for the value using the key?

if Key 100, expected output is NewYork

Comment: The goal is that you add some code of your own to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
grep 100 filename.csv | cut -d, -f3

Output:
New York
```

This will search the whole file for the value 100, and return all the values in the 3rd column of the matching rows.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU grep:

```
grep -Po '^100.....\K...........' file
```

or shorter:

```
grep -Po '^100.{5}\K.{11}' file
```

Output:

```
NewYork
```

Answer (score 1):

Awk splits lines by whitespace sequences (by default).
You could use that to write a condition on the first column.

In your example input, it looks like not CSV but columns with fixed width (except the header). If that's the case, then you can extract the name of the city as a substring:

```
awk '$1 == 100 { print substr($0, 9, 11); }' input.csv
```

Here 9 is the starting position of the city column, and 11 is its length.

If on the other hand your input file is not what you pasted, but really CSV (comma separated values), *and if there are no other embedded commas or newline characters* in the input, then you can write like this:

```
awk -F, '$1 == 100 { print $3 }' input.csv
```